# How to use PicoContainer for a constructor with paramenter

Tags: java, ioc-container, picocontainer

I am using PicoContainer and I have to add a component which has a constructor with paramenter. 
So I have

```
public abstract class IA {

   @Inject
   protected B b;

   public void useB(){
        b.useSomeMethodOfB();
   }
}

public interface IC{}

public class C implements IC{}

public class A extends IA{

     private IC mSomeOtherComponent;

     public A(IC someOtherComponent){
         mSomeOtherComponent = someOtherComponent
     }
}
```

Now to instatiate this component I have:

```
MutablePicoContainer context = new PicoBuilder().withAnnotatedFieldInjection().withCaching().build();
```

then

```
contex.addComponent(A.class, new A(new C()));
```

but when I call useB() method in the abstract class it returns null, it doesn't inject anything.
I think it's not right the way I added the component. I also tried;

```
ComponentParameter pr = new ComponentParameter(new C());
context.addComponent(IA.class, A.class, pr);
```

and

```
 ComponentParameter pr = new ComponentParameter(new C());
 context.addComponent(A.class, A.class, pr);
```

but it says that "A has unsatisfied dependency for fields B.

How could I solve it?

Comment: `contex.addComponent(B.class, new A(new C()));`? (I have heard of PicoContainer, but still not used it.)

Comment: I am new with it, as I told I don't think it's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so intuitive

```
public interface ThreadPool {  
 void setSize(int);  
}  

public class MyComp {  
 private ThreadPool threadPool;
 public MyComp(ThreadPool pool) {  
    threadPool = pool;  
    threadPool.setSize(size);  
 }  
}
```

In order to invoke the MyComp(ThreadPool pool) constructor you've to do the following :

```
DefaultPicoContainer pico = new DefaultPicoContainer();  
pico.addComponent(ThreadPool.class, DefaultThreadPool.class);  
pico.addComponent(MyComp.class, MyComp.class);

MyComp myComp = (MyComp)pico.getInstance(MyComp.class);
```

As you notice, the fact that you registred ThreadPool before instantiating MyComp, that will satisfy "greediest" condition to let PicoContainer invoke the parametrized constructor instead of the default one.

more information [here](http://picocontainer.codehaus.org/faq.html)

Cheers

Comment: he needs to inject both constructor and field

Comment: I hope I understood what you mean, you can see how I did it in one of the answers before, please check if it is what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have B in the container? If you can't inject it in the constructor you can use 
http://picocontainer.codehaus.org/multi-injection.html to inject both field and constructor

Answer (score 0):

I ended up injecting the constructor

```
    context.addComponent(IC.class, C.class);

    context.addComponent(A.class, A.class);
```

and in class A I injected the constructor so:

```
    @Inject
    private IC c;
```

So now depending on what I need I can add to the context whatever implementation of C class I need.

Comment: Hi but doing like that didn't work either, because it kept saying that B has not initialized... :/